# Determine a joint probablity density function

Tags: probability

Random variables X & Y's joint distribution is uniformly distributed over the region 2>y>x>0, determine joint pdf.

I just don't get it. It should be simple.

Answer (score 1):

To declare that $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed over some region $D$ is to ask that their joint density is
$$
f_{X,Y}=\frac{\mathbf 1_D}{|D|}.
$$
Can you compute $|D|$ in your case?

Answer (score 0):

**Draw** the region on which the joint density "lives." Make a $2\times 2$ square, with corners $(0,0)$, $(0,2)$, $(2,2)$, and $(0,2)$.  Your density function lives in the part of the square which is above the line $y=x$. Draw that line.

So the joint density lives on a certain triangle. Find the area of the triangle, and the joint density will drop out.

Comment: And what would the joint pdf be?

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}$ in the interior of the triangle we described, $0$ elsewhere.